# www.example.com loads nginx page but example.com loads wordpress correctly

Tags: nginx

I am pretty new to this so apologies if I am asking stupid questions.

I am using aapanel to manage my nginx webserver.

I have my domain setup and wordpress website working perfectly if you enter https://example.com, but if I try [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it loads the nginx page.

if I try https://www.example.com I get the aapanel login screen but it doesn't load correctly (white page with non formatted username/password fields in the top left corner).

nginx.conf

```
user  www www;
worker_processes auto;
error_log  /www/wwwlogs/nginx_error.log  crit;
pid        /www/server/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 51200;

events
    {
        use epoll;
        worker_connections 51200;
        multi_accept on;
    }

http
        {
#AAPANEL_FASTCGI_CONF_BEGIN
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_path /dev/shm/nginx-cache/wp levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m inactive=60m max_size=1g;
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
#AAPANEL_FASTCGI_CONF_END

        include       mime.types;
                #include luawaf.conf;

                include proxy.conf;

        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;
        client_header_buffer_size 32k;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
        client_max_body_size 50m;

        sendfile   on;
        tcp_nopush on;

        keepalive_timeout 60;

        tcp_nodelay on;

        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 64k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length  1k;
        gzip_buffers     4 16k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_types     text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/css application/xml;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied   expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_disable   "MSIE [1-6]\.";
        limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:10m;
                limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=perserver:10m;

        server_tokens off;
        access_log off;

server
    {
        listen 888;
        server_name phpmyadmin;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        root  /www/server/phpmyadmin;
            location ~ /tmp/ {
                return 403;
            }

        #error_page   404   /404.html;
        include enable-php.conf;

        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
        {
            expires      30d;
        }

        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
        {
            expires      12h;
        }

        location ~ /\.
        {
            deny all;
        }

        access_log  /www/wwwlogs/access.log;
    }
include /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

[image: DNS records]
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

many thanks in advance.

Comment: www.example.com and example.com are 2 different domains/URL. If you have configured nginx to work only for example.com, then the other one will not work.

Comment: Can you share the website setup you use? The nginx config and any other config you have used to host this

Comment: not sure if thats what you wanted... (edited the original post)

Comment: Do you have access to the server's terminal where nginx runs? Try to run `nginx -T` to give the full config output- put that in question

Comment: Basically, there is extra stuff in things like `www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/*.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh I solved it... just created another domain on aapanel and redirected!

Sorry to bother you all!